# Many-to-Many Relationship on the same table using Entity Framework is giving me grief

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm essentially trying to make a [Gantt Chart](https://www.gantt.com/). I have a type called `ProjectTask` and is as follows:

```
public class ProjectTask
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<ProjectTask> SubTasks { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<TaskDependency> Precedents { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<TaskDependency> Dependents { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the type holds subtasks which does not cause a problem. The problem arise when including the type `TaskDependency`.

```
public class TaskDependency
{
   public int PrecedentId { get; set; }
   public ProjectTask Precedent { get; set; }
   public int DependentId { get; set; }
   public ProjectTask Dependent { get; set; }
}
```

As you may have guessed, I'm using EntityFramework Code-First approach and SqlServer as a database provider. Here's the `ProjectDbContext` structure:

```
public class ProjectDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<ProjectTask> Tasks { get; set; }
   public DbSet<TaskDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }

   public ProjectDbContext([NotNull] DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<TaskDependency>()
         .HasKey(c => new { c.PrecedentId, c.DependentId });

      modelBuilder.Entity<TaskDependency>()
         .HasOne(td => td.Precedent)
         .WithMany(t => t.Dependents)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

      modelBuilder.Entity<TaskDependency>()
         .HasOne(td => td.Dependent)
         .WithMany(t => t.Precedents)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

`Dependencies` is a many-to-many entity on the same entity (`Tasks`) and that is because one task can depend on zero or more other tasks. It's important that when a task is deleted from the `Tasks` entity, the action is propegated to the `Dependencies` entity, hense the fluent API calls in the `OnModelCreating` override.

When executing `Add-Migration` in the package manager console, the migration code is generated, no problem. However, when executing `Update-Database`, or set up a static migration method to be called from the `Startup` class, I get the following error:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Dependencies] (
    [PrecedentId] int NOT NULL,
    [DependentId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Dependencies] PRIMARY KEY ([PrecedentId], [DependentId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Dependencies_Tasks_DependentId] FOREIGN KEY ([DependentId]) REFERENCES [Tasks] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Dependencies_Tasks_PrecedentId] FOREIGN KEY ([PrecedentId]) REFERENCES [Tasks] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
...
...
...
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Dependencies_Tasks_PrecedentId' on table 'Dependencies' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

There are StackOverflow entries that tackle this specific error, and other entries that tackle a many-to-many relationship on the same table, but, for the life of me, I can't find one that deals with both in one scenario.
What I'd like to know is, how to get this to work? How do I make a many-to-many relationship on the same table with a cascading effect?

Comment: Why do you want cascading delete? If you delete the TaskDependency it will also delete the projectTask. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi @klekmek . Thank you for responding.
Actually, no. What I want, basically, is when a ProjectTask is deleted, all the TaskDependency instances related to it are deleted too, and the deletion chain stops there. My thought was that I'll be able to achieve that by calling the fluent APIs in the way described in the question. Am I doing it wrong? If yes, what should the fluent APIs look like?

Comment: You have to define it the other way around. The ProjectTask has a cascading delete.